# Unexpected behavior while looping through block of lines

Tags: python, loops

I have a file which contains blocks of 11 lines of each item. I want to iterate through each block and extracting the data of each lines in the block. I have done it like this :

```
file_removed = open("input_removed.txt")
json_result = open("output_json.json", "w+")
datalist = []
while True:

    data = {}

    name = next(file_removed)
    name = re.sub("\n", "", name)

    data["name"] = name
    familyName = next(file_removed)
    familyName = re.sub("\n", "", familyName)

    data["familyName"] = familyName

    wGuideline = next(file_removed)
    wGuideline = re.sub("Watering guidelines\s+","", wGuideline)
    wGuideline = re.sub("\n", "", wGuideline)
    data["water"] = wGuideline

    FerLine = next(file_removed)
    FerLine = re.sub("Fertilizer suggestions\s+ ","",FerLine)
    FerLine = re.sub("\n", "", FerLine)
    data["fertilizer"] = FerLine

    MistLine = next(file_removed)
    MistLine = re.sub("Mist requirements\s+","",MistLine)
    MistLine = re.sub("\n", "", MistLine)
    data["mist"] = MistLine

    LightLine = next(file_removed)
    LightLine = re.sub("Light preferences\s+","", LightLine)
    LightLine = re.sub("\n", "", LightLine)
    data["light"] = LightLine

    TempLine = next(file_removed)
    TempLine = re.sub("Temperature preference\s+","",TempLine)
    TempLine = re.sub("\n", "", TempLine)
    data["temperature"] = TempLine

    print(TempLine)
    phLine = next(file_removed)
    phLine = re.sub("pH range\s+", "", phLine)
    phLine = re.sub("\n", "", phLine)
    data["ph"] = phLine

    AcidLine = next(file_removed)
    AcidLine = re.sub("Acidity preference\s+", "",TempLine)
    AcidLine = re.sub("\n", "", TempLine)
    data["acid"] = AcidLine

    ToxicLine = next(file_removed)
    ToxicLine = re.sub("Toxicity\s+", "",AcidLine)
    ToxicLine = re.sub("\n", "", AcidLine)
    data["toxic"] = ToxicLine

    ClimateLine = next(file_removed)
    ClimateLine = re.sub("Climate\s+", "",ClimateLine)
    ClimateLine = re.sub("\n", "", ClimateLine)
    data["climate"]= ClimateLine

    datalist.append(data)
    try:
        next(file_removed)
    except StopIteration:
        break;
```

You can see the print(TempLine) i implemented to check if my version is working. But after the FIRST iteration, each WHILE loop iterates only through one line!

Can some one explain this behavior for me ?

Comment: Err... could you provide an example of your input file? It looks like you're doing a lot of work there you needn't be...

Comment: @cdarke can you try with more than one input ? I cant post my input here because of confidential reason.

Comment: My bad.  Note that there are 12 calls to `next()` on each iteration, and you are not capturing the line read by the last one in the `try` block.

Comment: Do you have a blank line between each block of 11 ?  If not, then your final `next()` in the loop is the problem.

Comment: @cdarke my bad,  i forgot a next line at the start. let me try again

Comment: @cdarke it should work now, but i dont understand why the extra next() causes this behavior ??

Comment: It causes it because you are not processing the record read.  The second block will start at its 2nd line, the third block will start at its 3rd line, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your last `next()` in the `try` block reads the first line of the **next** block, but does not capture it, so that line is lost.  Each iteration reads 12 records, not 11, but you only process 11.

Try this (there are two new lines and one changed line):

```
import re

file_removed = open("input_removed.txt")
json_result = open("output_json.json", "w+")
datalist = []
name = None                                   # Added

while True:

    data = {}

    if name is None:                          # Added
        name = next(file_removed)

    name = re.sub("\n", "", name)

    data["name"] = name
    familyName = next(file_removed)
    familyName = re.sub("\n", "", familyName)

    data["familyName"] = familyName


    wGuideline = next(file_removed)
    wGuideline = re.sub("Watering guidelines\s+","", wGuideline)
    wGuideline = re.sub("\n", "", wGuideline)
    data["water"] = wGuideline

    FerLine = next(file_removed)
    FerLine = re.sub("Fertilizer suggestions\s+ ","",FerLine)
    FerLine = re.sub("\n", "", FerLine)
    data["fertilizer"] = FerLine

    MistLine = next(file_removed)
    MistLine = re.sub("Mist requirements\s+","",MistLine)
    MistLine = re.sub("\n", "", MistLine)
    data["mist"] = MistLine

    LightLine = next(file_removed)
    LightLine = re.sub("Light preferences\s+","", LightLine)
    LightLine = re.sub("\n", "", LightLine)
    data["light"] = LightLine

    TempLine = next(file_removed)
    TempLine = re.sub("Temperature preference\s+","",TempLine)
    TempLine = re.sub("\n", "", TempLine)
    data["temperature"] = TempLine

    print(TempLine)
    phLine = next(file_removed)
    phLine = re.sub("pH range\s+", "", phLine)
    phLine = re.sub("\n", "", phLine)
    data["ph"] = phLine

    AcidLine = next(file_removed)
    AcidLine = re.sub("Acidity preference\s+", "",TempLine)
    AcidLine = re.sub("\n", "", TempLine)
    data["acid"] = AcidLine

    ToxicLine = next(file_removed)
    ToxicLine = re.sub("Toxicity\s+", "",AcidLine)
    ToxicLine = re.sub("\n", "", AcidLine)
    data["toxic"] = ToxicLine

    ClimateLine = next(file_removed)
    ClimateLine = re.sub("Climate\s+", "",ClimateLine)
    ClimateLine = re.sub("\n", "", ClimateLine)
    data["climate"]= ClimateLine

    datalist.append(data)
    try:
        name = next(file_removed)          # Changed
    except StopIteration:
        break;
```

There are other improvements that could be made to this code, but further changes  would detract from the immediate problem.

Comment: Thank you, this explained a lot !